html behavior inside R-shiny
I have a Rmd file with some math expression which I kint it inside R and get a html file:
---
title: "Random Markdown with Math"
author: "Example Author"
date: "2024-07-15"
output: 
  html_document
    
---

## Introduction

This document contains various mathematical expressions and formulas rendered using LaTeX.

## Basic Arithmetic

Here are some basic arithmetic expressions:

- Addition: $1 + 1 = 2$
- Subtraction: $5 - 3 = 2$
- Multiplication: $4 \times 2 = 8$
- Division: $\frac{10}{2} = 5$

## Quadratic Formula

The quadratic formula is used to solve equations of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. It is given by:

$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
$$

## Pythagorean Theorem

In a right-angled triangle, the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides:

$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
$$

Now I'm trying to embed this into a modal in my shiny app :
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(
    top = 10, left = 10,
    actionButton("show_guide", "Show User Guide")
  ),
  tags$div(
    id = "guide_modal",
    class = "modal fade",
    tabindex = "-1",
    `aria-labelledby` = "guide_modal_label",
    `aria-hidden` = "true",
    tags$div(
      class = "modal-dialog modal-lg",
      tags$div(
        class = "modal-content",
        tags$div(
          class = "modal-header",
          tags$h5(class = "modal-title", id = "guide_modal_label", "User Guide"),
          tags$button(
            type = "button",
            class = "close",
            `data-dismiss` = "modal",
            `aria-label` = "Close",
            tags$span(`aria-hidden` = "true", HTML("&times;"))
          )
        ),
        tags$div(
          class = "modal-body",
          tags$iframe(src = "user_guide.html", width = "100%", height = "600px", frameborder = 0)
        ),
        tags$div(
          class = "modal-footer",
          tags$button(
            type = "button",
            class = "btn btn-secondary",
            `data-dismiss` = "modal",
            "Close"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$show_guide, {
    runjs('$("#guide_modal").modal("show");')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

But the shiny app has quite a strange behavior ! sometimes everything is fine :

And sometime, when I re-render the app, the math expression is messed up :

My html file is static. I'm not re-rendering the rmd every time. I just copied the html file inside the www folder and run the app !
Any idea how could I fix this ?!
PS: It has to be in the modal format !

I think looking at the rendered HTML would be a good first step, to see what's different between the two.

It's not reproducible for me, however, there are errors in the JS console when opening the .html. Also, did you notice the warning? Warning: includeHTML() was provided a path that appears to be a complete HTML document. Path: www/user_guide.html Use tags$iframe() to include an HTML document. You can either ensure path is accessible in your app or document (see e.g. shiny::addResourcePath()) and pass the relative path to the src argument. Or you can read the contents of path and pass the contents to srcdoc.

@Jan, sorry there was a mistake, I have corrected the code, maybe now you could reproduce the results !

@miken32, I did ! The rendered html file is absolutely fine. I can open it in my browser and it works !
but when I put it in shiny sometimes it is not able to show the expressions correctly !

Unfortunately I still can't reproduce this, it works fine for me. Do you have any specific steps which one can apply in order to see this behavior?

@Jan, Not really !
I render (knit) the rmd and copy the produced html output (user_guide.html) to my www folder. Then Run the above app. the first few runs are fine then suddenly it start to messing up the math expressions ! quite randomly !

As an alternative you could render your Rmd file as PDF instead of HTML and display it via an iframe.
